# XAML style trigger on double value

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I want to display specific images according to a double-field in my datasource.

This field contains values from 0.0 to 100.0 and I got four images, ranging from 0-25, 26-50, 51-75 and 76-100.

How can I achieve this in XAML?

My current trigger:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="Suitability" Value="50">
     <Setter Property="Source" Value="image2.png" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But this ain't working for ranged values, just for static values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a view model? The easiest way would be to add a separate enumeration property to your VM that the view can bind to:

```
public SuitabilityLevel SuitabilityLevel
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Suitability < 25)
        {
            return SuitabilityLevel.Low;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<Trigger Property="SuitabilityLevel" Value="Low">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="image1.png" />
</Trigger>
```

No view model? Use a converter.

Comment: I haven't got a ViewModel, but the additional enumeration looks fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you look at converters ... it basically should convert a double to a string... And in the converter logic you could also include your ranges ... or call other business logic...

Here is how to write converters and what they are used for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx

Hope this helps...